# Determining energy of gamma-rays after alpha-decay of Am-241

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation

So it turns into Np, and electrons just falling into 'free new' levels and emmiting, right?

[image]

Give me a link where to read, please, if it's very easy to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [a complicated decay](http://ie.lbl.gov/toi/nuclide.asp?iZA=950241) with many possible modes--there are one or more gamma associated with every alpha line (except, perhaps the highest energy one).

It is essentially impossible to compute the photon spectrum from first principles; they must be measured and doing so well is a delicate experiment.

Comment: Thank you! Can you say, what is the reason of 26.3 keV (Am gamma peak)?

Comment: That's a prompt gamma in coincidence with the alpha decay.

Answer (score 1):

241-Am emits several gamma rays, but 35.9% gamma rays will have 59.5412 keV energy that can be easily detected with a scintillation detector fitted with NaI (Tl) crystal.

The following Reference also provides various alpha energies from 241-Am.

Reference:
WWW Table of Radioactive Isotopes
http://ie.lbl.gov/toi/nuclide.asp?iZA=950241